# RESTful web service's response

Tags: jakarta-ee, rest

Let's say I have the following model

```
Course
Student
```

The URI:

```
/courses/1
```

should return the following information about a particular course:

```
Name
Number
Date
Instructor
```

and:
    /courses

should return a list of above mentioned information.

I'm not sure about the 'return' part. If this was a JAX-WS service we would get the information about the course in question, create XML, stick that XML into a SOAP envelope and XML over HTTP to the client.

Also in a 'normal' web application, in response to:

```
/courses
```

A `List<Course>` would be `request.addAttribute(-)`'d to the JSP to render an HTML table. What is supposed to happen for a RESTful web service? Should the contents of the `List` be directly written to the output stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RESTful Web Services you define what will be the output. It can be a plain text, JSON, HTML, XML or whatever you would like. The RESTful endpoint is able to produce what you like (what you define in the `@Produces` annotation).

Basically, you get what you serve, so if you invoke a GET request on your RESTful resource which serves HTML - you'll get rendered HTML page. If it serves the XML - you'll get XML, just like in SOAP Web Services.

You can use the same semantics you used for SOAP Web Services. So if someone hits the `/courses` link, you could return whole list of courses (i.e. in a JSON format).

This could be useful for future references: [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e8)